# This animation is not functioning in this method

Tags: objective-c, ios

I'm having a lot of trouble figuring this one out. This method is imported from another class into my viewController.m It works fine if I copy the code into an IBAction in the same file. And the "test midi" is logging when it is supposed to. So the IBOutlets and animation code seem OK but for some reason this method does not do what it is supposed to

```
 - (void) source:(theSource*)data dataReceived:(const dataList *)theList
    {

       led.animationImages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[UIImage imageNamed:@"led-highlighted.png"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"led-passive.png"],nil];
        led.animationDuration = 0.3;
        led.animationRepeatCount = 20;
        [led startAnimating];
     NSLog(@"test");}
```

it also doesn't work if I simply put this to swap the image. The method is being called because it is logging to console.

```
 midiLed.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@ "led-highlighted.png"];
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem may lie in how you are calling this method. It should be on the main thread, and after calling it, your code should return to the run loop (i.e. your code should be "done") before changes to the user interface will have effect.

If this doesn't help you find it, please share the code calling this method.

Answer (score 0):

What thread is `-source:dataReceived:` being called on? If you're using CoreMIDI, your MIDI-received function will get called on a separate, high-priority thread.

You should not touch the UI from a non-main thread, because UIKit isn't thread safe.

Here's one way to get the UI running on the main thread:

```
- (void) source:(theSource*)data dataReceived:(const dataList *)theList
{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        led.animationImages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[UIImage imageNamed:@"led-highlighted.png"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"led-passive.png"],nil];
        led.animationDuration = 0.3;
        led.animationRepeatCount = 20;
        [led startAnimating];
        NSLog(@"test");
    });
}
```